# Android - Is Adapter is super interface of all *Adapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I am new to android and learning about the adapters. For this i am using the Android [official](https://developer.android.com/) documentation.

I am confused about one thing regarding adapters. Is the [Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZu15.png) is super interface of all the adapters classes in android?

If **yes** then why this is not mentioned on [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) page that it is super interface of all the adapters in android. In fact it is on the top of hierarchy. See picture below:

[image]

and even this interface is also not in the hierarchy [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter): See picture below:

[image]

If **no** then how the methods of [Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZu15.png) interface are implemented?

Or may be my understandings are wrong. Is this interface available to be implemented by custom user defined class or no it is implemented internally, or something else? Thank you very much in advance for the explanation and clarification of this confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the Adapter is super interface of all the adapters classes in android?

No. It is for the classic `AdapterView` family of views (e.g., `ListView`, `Spinner`) and its set of adapters. `RecyclerView.Adapter`, `PagerAdapter`, etc. are unrelated to `Adapter`, other than they all fill the same sort of role.

> and even this interface is also not in the hierarchy here: See picture below:

`ArrayAdapter` implements `ThemedSpinnerAdapter`, which extends `Adapter`. The JavaDocs do not point out the inheritance hierarchy of implemented interfaces.

Comment: So, you mean this `Adapter` is used for filling the `ListView`, `Spinner` etc, right?

Comment: @Sunny: Implementations of `Adapter` are, yes. Implementations of `RecyclerView.Adapter` are used with `RecyclerView`. Implementations of `PagerAdapter` are used with `ViewPager`. And so on.

Comment: But i can use the `ArrayAdapter` for `ListView`, then why to use the `Adapter`? Is there any special case when the `Adapter` is useful?

Comment: Can you do a little example of `Adapter` interface with `ListView`. I will be glad

Comment: @Sunny you can find any example of using ListView and Adapter by searching for `arrayadapter android listview example site:stackoverflow.com` in Google.

Comment: @Sunny: `Adapter` is an interface. `ArrayAdapter` is a class. `ArrayAdapter` adapts Java arrays and `java.util.List` implementations, such as `ArrayList`. There are many other data structures in the world, and there are not always specific adapter classes for them. For other data structures, you either create your own class that implements `Adapter` or you create your own class that extends `BaseAdapter`. And most of this is obsolete, as `RecyclerView` has replaced most uses of the `AdapterView` family of classes.